# iNEXT warning messages: In sqrt(var_obs) : NaNs produced

Tags: warnings, inext

I get the warning messages:

> In sqrt(var_obs): NaNs produced

after I run the iNEXT code `out.raw <- iNEXT(pwa, datatype="incidence_raw", endpoint = 125)` in r. When I run the same code for another dataset it works fine, without any errors. Any ideas why it can happen? Should I ignore this warning?

My data type is incidence_raw (for example see data - ciliates). I use a csv. file and the following code: `pw1 <- as.matrix(apply(pw[,-1],2,as.integer))`, `row.names(mpw) <- pw[,1]`, `pa1 <- as.matrix(apply(pa[,-1],2,as.integer))`, `row.names(mpa) <- pa[,1]`, `pwa = list(PW = pw1, PA = pa1)`, `out.raw <- iNEXT(pwa, datatype="incidence_raw", endpoint = 125)`. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

This warning indicates that `var_obs` has negative or non-numeric values in it. To see how var_obs is computed, check out the source code: https://github.com/JohnsonHsieh/iNEXT/blob/3b53e0b1818d1086b86fc59cfe793a545d4a11eb/R/EstIndex.R.

I would guess that your original data is the source of the issue.